# WooCommerce Data. C#

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce

I receiving data from woocommerce.

Receiving it like this.

```
  RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");


    WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
    //Get all products
    var orders = await wc.GetOrders();


    foreach (var order in orders) {

        Debug.WriteLine($"Currency: {order.currency},Date:{order.date_created},Adress: {order.billing},  Total Cost: {order.total}");

    }
```

In this part all okay. But I have received Date and Time in wrong format.

```
Date:8/18/2016 8:33:12 AM
```

On website is not UTC , on website UTC+2

Can I convert it to UTC+2 , 24 hours format?

Comment: just add 2 to the {hour} in your time...

Comment: Don't understood. I have Date and Time in one string @JayGould

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Parse` with the appropriate format then call `ToString()` with the format you want it in. So If you know you're getting +2:00 you can do:

```
string date = order.date_created + "+2:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
string convertedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```